# Is there any Performance Issue joining Row based Table to Clustered Columnstore Index Table

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, columnstore

Is there any Performance Degradation joining Row based Table to Clustered Columnstore Index Table? Does SQL Server have any guidance for or against this?

We have a table that is 2 million rows, and has a clustered Columnstore Index.

We want to join to couple table, which row-based (Not Columnstore), to a regular Row Binary-tree table. Is there any performance issues joining , or having a Clustered Columnstore index with a regular table?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is extremely generic, but it is just barely possible to answer it. What you are describing is only problematic on SQL Server 2012. Starting in SQL Server 2014, the query optimizer has better support for joining columnstore tables to rowstore tables. Quoting from a Microsoft [white paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/enhancements-to-sql-server-column-stores/) describing new features in SQL Server 2014:

> Batch processing in SQL Server 2012 supported only the most heavily
>   used query patterns in data warehousing scenarios, for example, inner
>   but not outer joins, and group-by-aggregate but not scalar aggregates.
>   Query plan segments using batch processing had a rigid shape; the join
>   order was fixed and generated heuristically based on cardinality
>   estimates. Query plans had to prepare for the possibility of a
>   “bailout” to row-by-row processing, in case of insufficient memory
>   during execution.
>
> The upcoming release of SQL Server [2014] extends batch processing
>   capabilities in several ways.  We consider batch execution for
>   iterators anywhere in the query plan, regardless of whether their
>   inputs are using batch execution, and regardless of whether the data
>   originates in a column store or row store.  The join order for batch
>   execution is no longer a fixed one generated heuristically.  Batch
>   processing is supported for all SQL Server join types, union all, and
>   scalar aggregation. Finally, we have done extensive work on memory
>   management and spilling support for batch mode operators.
>
> In SQL Server 2012 the transition between row and batch processing
>   happens only at prescribed points in the plan, and the transition
>   between batch and row processing occurs only when absolutely
>   necessary. This limitation is cumbersome and the forthcoming release
>   of SQL Server has a completely new model for dealing with batch to row
>   mode transitions.
>
> Like the sortedness of output rows, the execution mode is treated as a
>   physical property of a query plan iterator, and the physical property
>   framework is used to manage execution mode transitions. It is now
>   possible to transition from one execution mode to another at any point
>   in an execution plan.

Based on this question and others, you have a lot of doubts about columnstore technology. That is perfectly natural. Your best bet is to try a small scale proof of concept in your environment. That is the only way to know if columnstore is a good fit for your workload. You won't be able to get the answers that you need just from asking questions describing hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: That last sentence should be on a sticky.